# How to return one row from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Field Type:

```
Date1 = varchar(10)
Date2 = int
```

Tables:

```
tblName

Num(pk)         Name            Open
0909            John Doe        Yes
0908            Jason Kelly     Yes


tblOwes

Num(pk)     Date1           Date2           Amnt        Type
0909        11/14/2020      20201114        350.00      12
0909        11/15/2020      20201115        250.00      12
0909        10/29/2020      20201029        650.00      13
0909        09/12/2020      20200912        898.00      12
0908        08/29/2020      20200829        650.00      12
0908        09/15/2020      20200915        250.00      12
0908        09/14/2020      20200914        350.00      12
0908        08/12/2020      20200812        898.00      13
```

Query:

```
select tn.Num, tn.Name, to.Date1, to.Amnt
from tblName tn
inner join tblOwes to
    on tn.Num = to.Num
where to.Date1 = (select top 1 to.Date1 from tblOwes where to.Num = tn.Num order by to.Date1 Desc)
```

I would only like one entry from `tblOwes`, the most recent by `Date1` column, for each account in `tblName` where Type is 12 and Open is Yes

Desired Result:

```
Num     Name            Date1       Amnt        Type        Open
0909    John Doe        11/15/2020  250.00      12          Yes
0908    Jason Kelly     09/15/2020  250.00      12          Yes
```

Right now it's returning four entries for John and four for Jason

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Sorry, SQL dbms

Comment: Which one? MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes... So i have to update the ? because I have to check for other columns too.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses `row_number()`:

```
select tn.Num, tn.Name, o.Date1, o.Amnt
from tblName tn join
     (select o.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by o.num order by o.date1 desc) as seqnum
      from tblOwes o
     ) o
     on tn.Num = o.Num and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hmmmmm Is this in SQL?

Comment: yes it is SQL , and I think Gordon is missing a condition on join : `AND o.seqnum = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the query you're looking for

```
with o_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by num order by date1 desc) as rn
    from tblOwes
    where [Type]=12)
select n.Num, t.[Name], o.Date1, o.Amnt, o.[Type], n.[Open]
from tblName n
     join o_cte o on n.Num = o.Num
where n.[Open]='Yes'
      and o.rn=1
order by n.Num desc;
```

Alternately, if it's 'Name' from the tblNames table that's unique (across 'num'), then the PARTITION BY would be n.[Name] and the query could look like this

```
with o_cte as (
    select o.*, row_number() over (partition by n.[Name] order by date1 desc) as rn
    from tblName n
         join tblOwes o on n.Num = o.Num
    where o.[Type]=12
          and n.[Open]='Yes')
select n.Num, t.[Name], o.Date1, o.Amnt, o.[Type], n.[Open]
from tblName n
     join o_cte o on n.Num = o.Num
where 
      and o.rn=1
order by n.Num desc;
```

Comment: I tried that but i get John Doe four entries from the result because there are four entries in the tblOwes

Comment: Thank you for the help. I targeted tblOwes and was able to join with tblName and it worked like a charm. Didn't even need to use CTE! Appreciate it again +1